# Hashing by either one of two members

Tags: c++, hash

While this question is with regard to c++, it is a general hashing question which might answer for other languages as well.

I have a class that is identified by **either** one of 2 members it holds (let's call them device & name).

```
class Foo {
    static const int NO_DEVICE = 0;

    bool isDeviceSet() {
        return device != NO_DEVICE;
    }

private:
    int device;
    std::string name;
};
```

I would like to identify a `Foo` instance with priority to the `device` (when it's set).
Meaning, when `device` is set I would like to hash according to `device` (**alone!** - so that two `Foo`s with the same `device` and different `name`s will be considered the same object hash wise).
And when the `device` is not set I would like to hash according to `name`.

**My question:**

> Is hashing by either one of the members safe enough?

For example, hashing by either one would look like this:

```
namespace std {
    size_t hash<Foo>::operator()(Foo const& f) const {
        if (f.isDeviceSet()) {
            return std::hash<int>()(f.deviceId);
        }
        return std::hash<std::string>()(f.name);
     }
}
```

The problem with this is that one could argue that (according to each hash function's implementation), the probability for 2 different `Foo`s, one with a `device` set and one without a `device` set, to have the same hash code is unknown (however highly unlikely).

- Consider an int hash function that converts to a string and calls string's hash - this will result in `Foo{2, "bar"}` and `Foo{0, "2"}` having the same hash code.

On the other hand, I'm not sure whether combining `isDeviceSet()` in the hash would really give better results (for the general case - obviously it solves the example in the bullet above):

```
namespace std {
    size_t hash<Foo>::operator()(Foo const& f) const {
        if (f.isDeviceSet()) {
            std::pair<bool, int> p(f.isDeviceSet(), f.device);
            boost::hash< std::pair<bool, int> > hasher;
            return hasher(p);
        }
        std::pair<bool, std::string> p(f.isDeviceIdSet(), f.name);
        boost::hash< std::pair<bool, std::string> > hasher;
        return hasher(p);
     }
}
```

Any insights / other hash ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashing always goes together with equality.

You need to define an equality operation which does match elements that you consider equal, and does not match elements that you consider not equal.

Then you define a hash function which must has all elements that equality considers equal to the same hash code. There is no requirement at all for elements that are considered not equal.

Any algorithm involving hashing must survive equal hash codes for unequal objects without problems; it is never possible to guarantee different hash codes for different objects if there are more possible objects than possible hash codes. Even if your hash function returns just 0, any algorithm using it should just work, except possible less efficient.

When you consider how complicated to make your hash function: It should just make the sets of existing objects with the same hash code small. It doesn't have to be perfect, unless you have a hash table that is *really* performance critical. But then the hash function itself is also performance critical to some degree.

Comment: so if my equality operator checks `isDeviceSet()` and compares `device` or `name` accordingly, I should be ok even with the first hash function - since in my example the `Foo`s are not equal. Thanks.